# Databinding memory leaking

Tags: data-binding, viewmodel, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

Is there possibility below this method causes memory leak in anyway.

```
 android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.showList(v)}
```

My understanding is that, view reference is passed to view model, view model then uses reference and set its content to the view. On the fragment destroy, associated viewBinder is also destroy, the whole screen is releases from the memory. Are there anyway passed view reference going to be hold in the View Model once fragment is destroyed? I don't think so.

Do you recommend to use this notation? Can you share your experience if this is possibility of memory leak?

Comment: Don't think so; just check the generated sources and not the XML... or profile the app.

Comment: @Martin Zeitler, That's what I believe, There is no where it going to hold reference of it , we just pass reference from one function call another and make use the reference to set its value to the view.

Comment: Leaking `Context` is usually the worst - and profiling can identify critical leaks. Minor leftovers in RAM aren't that bad, unless they accumulate repetitively - when profiling, one should test such situations. Just automate a stress-test with instrumentation, in order to be certain about it.

Answer (score 3):

It can be memory leak in given scenario:

Let's say you click on view and this method `viewModel.showList(v)` get invoked along with view reference passed to it.

Now imagine that you've global variable **`globalViewRef`** in `ViewModel` that stores reference to this view, for example:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel(){

    lateinit var globalViewRef: View

    fun showList(v: View){
        globalViewRef = v // Storing view reference globally for future methods/purpose etc.
    }
}
```

And your `ViewModel` is shared across fragments with **activity** context, in such scenario if **configuration change** happens your `viewModel` leaks **global view object** due to change of context.

---

So, things to take in mind:

1. Never store `view/context` globally in `ViewModel` class *(Use it locally inside method only if necessary)*.
2. If there's something you need hardly to store globally then override `onCleared()` & clean up reference there as it is the last call on `ViewModel` when it's going to destroy state *(Consider this when `ViewModel` is not being shared across activity context)*.

If you've both things covered then there's no memory leak in your case that I can find of.

Comment: Thanks for heads up, I understand your case, its bad idea to have view as internal member in view model and maintaining view reference, that's violation of MVVM. 

You are completely safe unless and until you never hold reference of view in view model , that's what you mean to be here. Thanks again.